# Anime about magic in a time before modern technology

Tags: story-identification, anime

In the first episode a girl is riding in a carriage and at some point a man shows up with a tattoo thing on his hand and takes out a bunch of knights or bandits. After all that is over the girl asks the guy if he would enter a non romantic contract. I also think that if you had the tattoo you are recognized as a noble, that could be wrong though.

I only watched the first 2 episodes sometime between 2014 and 2017 on YouTube. I don't remember much other than there was this room with a giant contraption that gave off this light that was the same color as the main character's magic tattoo. I don't think the mc was recognized as a noble and that is why he had to forge a contract with the girl. The girl also used the contract as a means to escape an arranged contract to a noble.

Comment: You have a nice start here but can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when did you watch this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Grancrest Senki](https://myanimelist.net/anime/34279/Grancrest_Senki)

The girl in the carriage is Siluca Meletes. She is appointed to Lord Villar as his mage. On the way to his castle, she is ambushed by his enemies.

[image: Siluca Meletes]

The man with the tatoo is Theo Cornaro. He's a new noble who fights for honorable reasons. He fights off the bandits and saves Siluca. After seeing his heroic display, Siluca decides to flee from her contract with Lord Villar and work for Theo as she believes he is the right person to work for.

[image: Theo Cornaro]

The tatoo is not really a tatoo, but a Crest. The more crests one has, the stronger the effect and the more influence such a person has. There used to be just a single Crest, the Grancrest. Due to invasions from Chaos, the Crests were scattered and aquired by different Lords. Only by collecting all Crests can the Grancrest be completed and Chaos defeated. A nice perk is you also become emperor.

[image: Theo activating his crest]

The room with the giant contraption at the start is important and I will not spoil that here. The scene in question is the opening scene and it features the marriage of Alexis Douse and Marrine Kreische. Their marriage would form the Grancrest once more. Chaos however does not agree with this plan and interferes.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I had been searching for a while.